# How to clean empty array objects and renumber them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a JavaScript object like

```
{0: [], 1: [0: 'a', 1: 'b'], 2: [], 3: [0: '20']}
```

I want to get rid of the empty slots in this object and renumber the remaining one, so it has a normal order (0, 1, 2).

I use this function:

```
function clean(obj) {
    for (var propName in obj) {
        if (obj[propName] === null || obj[propName].length == 0 || obj[propName] === undefined) {
            delete obj[propName];
        }
    }
}
```

Which clears the object, but then I get

```
{1: [0: 'a', 1: 'b'], 3: [0: '20']}
```

But how do I make 1 to 0 and 3 to 1?

Comment: seems weird to treat an object like an array.

Comment: Is it even possible to create an object like this -  `{ 1: [0: 'a', 1: 'b'] }` ?

Comment: @planet_hunter no, it would throw a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's a problem with your question since the definition of your first object does not pass JS compilation. The array elements are given a "key" with the index, you wrote...  `1: [0: 'a', 1: 'b']` which should be either:

```
1: {0: 'a', 1: 'b'}
```

or

```
1: ['a','b']
```

You are obviously mixing up between the index of an **array**, and the `keys` of an **object**.

Here you are giving the object keys the name of their index within their array. So perhaps you are asking one of three questions. (I'll answer each):

```
// 1. Clean [[], ['a','b'], [], '20']
// returning: [['a','b'], ['20']]  
// and not using params at all. 

// 2. Clean {0: [], 1: ['a','b'], 2: [], 3: ['20']}
// returning: {0: ['a','b'], 1: ['20']}

// 3. Clean {0: {}, 1: {0: 'a', 1: 'b'}, 2: {}, 3: {0: '20'}}
// returning: {0: {0: 'a', 1:'b'}, 1: {0: '20'}}
```

The fastest way, keeping your function intact, would be to add a new "indexer" at the bottom of your function, correcting the keys. We can use ES6 as follows:

```
 // if to delete...
 let oldKey = paramName;
 let newKey = (obj.keys().indexOf(oldKey)) - 1;
 delete obj[oldKey].assign(o, {[newKey]: o[oldKey] })[oldKey];
```

This is not very clear.

The clearest way is to use another object and populate the next element only if the original has a value, starting with index zero and increasing it.

```
function cleanup(obj) {
  let newObj = {};
  let idx = 0;
  for (var propName in obj) {
    let prop = obj[propName];
    console.log('prop', propName, JSON.stringify(prop))

    if (prop !== null 
     && prop !== undefined
     && JSON.stringify(prop) != "[]" // not empty array
     && JSON.stringify(prop) !== "{}") { // not empty obj
      newObj[idx] = prop;
      idx++;
    }
  }
  return newObj; 
}
```

See [my JS fiddle which shows this](https://jsfiddle.net/pashute/er5o4shm/).

You could also use the object's keys() method to get an array of the keynames in the order you would get them from the iterator. For the array you could use the splice(0,idx) to remove that element out.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp

Or you can use the split, but then you have to work "backwards", otherwise the for loop will not work correctly. So first get the propnames, and then work from the last one to the first popping as you go along.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this detailed answer. Worked like a charm! I hope it's going to help others who face the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using an `Array` instead of an `Object`, but you could do something like this:

```js
var obj = {0: [], 1: ['a', 'b'], 2: [], 3: ['20']};

var newObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function (acc, k) {
  var objVal = obj[k];
  if (objVal.length) {
    acc[Object.keys(acc).length] = objVal;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming arrays as properties, you could filter by length (with a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)) and assign this array to an object.

```js
var data = { 0: [], 1: ['a', 'b'], 2: [], 3: ['20'] },
    clean = Object.assign({}, Object.values(data).filter(({ length }) => length));

console.log(clean);
```

Comment: Hi Nina, nice solution, could you comment on the logic in this statement `({length})`?

Comment: it's a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), which means taking the property of the object as variable.

Comment: Will `Object.values` always guarantee the correct order?

Comment: @MarkMeyer, the so called *integer index* keys (positive 32 bit values, like indices of arrays) are sorted first. so yes.

Comment: Interesting @NinaScholz. I didn’t know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the index value is implicit

```js
const data = {
    0: [],
    1: ['a', 'b'],
    2: [],
    3: ['20']
}

const newData = {};

for (const property in data) {
    if (data[property].length !== 0) {
        newData[property] = data[property]
    }
}

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion. Also do not use index in array declarations: `[0: 'a', 1: 'b']` should be `['a', 'b']`.

```
const data = {0: [], 1: ['a', 'b'], 2: [], 3: ['20']};

const dataArray = Object.values(data);
let result = {};
let index = 0;

dataArray.forEach(d => {
  if (d.length) Object.assign(result, {[index++]: d});
})

// result --> {0: ['a', b'], 1: ['20']}
```